# Possible Bug on Django 1.11 with multitable Inheritance or possible bug on python 3.5 or am i?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

Using python 3.5.2 and django 1.11 multitable inheritance like this:

```
class Artist(ArtistParent):
    biography = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=settings.IMAGES_FOLDER)
    owner = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User", related_name="my_artists",
                              null=True, blank=True, on_delete=deletion.SET_NULL)


class SimilarBand(ArtistParent):
    pass
```

Every work out just fine, but using the ORM interface:

```
>>> ArtistParent.objects.all().delete()
(0, {})
>>> SimilarBand.objects.all().delete()
(0, {})
>>> ArtistParent.objects.all().delete()
(0, {})
>>> SimilarBand.objects.all().delete()
(0, {})
>>> SimilarBand.objects.create(name="Similar Band Test")
<SimilarBand: Similar Band Test>
>>> SimilarBand.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<SimilarBand: Similar Band Test>]>
>>> ArtistParent.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<ArtistParent: Similar Band Test>]>
>>> SimilarBand.objects.all().count()
1
>>> ArtistParent.objects.all().count()
1
>>> len(ArtistParent.objects.all())
1
>>> len(SimilarBand.objects.all())
1
>>> [print(o) for o in ArtistParent.objects.all()]
Similar Band Test
[None]
>>> [print(o) for o in SimilarBand.objects.all()]
Similar Band Test
[None]
>>> [print(o) for o in ArtistParent.objects.filter(similarband__isnull=False)]
Similar Band Test
[None]
>>>
```

My bug is about that second None that iterating over the queryset brings, is that normal? or is a bug on the Manager?

However, it works right if i use a for construct like this:

```
>>> [print(i) for i in list(SimilarBand.objects.all())]
Similar Band Test
[None]
>>> for i in list(SimilarBand.objects.all()):
...     print(i)
... 
Similar Band Test
```

Either way, i'm using a serpy Serializer, and give an error, when i pass the queryset.

Thanks for the Help

UPDATE:

As instructed in the comment / answer it was i who was miss using the list comprenhension construct (my mistake)

Neither has to do anything whit the serpy lib, My error turns to be something with the framework:

[![

---

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgjYA.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgjYA.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the manager, or indeed with Django at all. A list comprehension always constructs a list; that is its main purpose. But the only thing you're doing inside that list comp is calling `print()`, which returns None. So the result of that entire expression is a list containing a single None, which the shell helpfully prints for you.

Really, you should not use list comprehensions for their side effects. Use a proper loop.

Comment: It turns out that the "None" error that i'm getting is a http header content negotiation problem, that the framework is not handling very well